# Выделить активный пункт меню, не затрагивая другие

Tags: javascript, php

помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в скрипте для добавления класса active ссылке на которой пользователь находится. Либо использовать другой скрипт
Спасибо за помощь

```js
try {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('.right1 a.button8');
  var url = document.location.href;
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (url == el[i].href) {
      el[i].className += ' :active';
    };
  };
} catch (e) {}
```

```css
a.button8 {
  color: #0a684f;
}

a.button8:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

a.button8:active {
  color: #ef920d;
}
```

```html
<div class="right1">
  <a href="#" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Left</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="right1">
  <a href="/2" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Center</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="right1">
  <a href="/3" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Right</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали сами?

Comment: В прикрепленном коде

Comment: `document.getElementById('right1')` - В Вашем html-е нет элемента с `id="right1"`

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляете не класс `active`, а псевдокласс `:active`, который срабатывает тогда, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку. Если вы нажмете на ссылку в своем примере, она подсветится нужным цветом. Вот рабочий вариант. Немного поменял код.

```js
var url = "/2";
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.right1 a.button8[href="'+url+'"]');
if(el.length > 0){
  el.forEach(function(item,key){
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
a.button8 {
  color: #0a684f;
}

a.button8:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

a.button8.active {
  color: #ef920d;
}
```

```html
<div class="right1">
  <a href="#" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Left</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="right1">
  <a href="/2" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Center</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="right1">
  <a href="/3" class="button8">
    <div class="icontext">Right</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только как вот взять открытую ссылку? var url = "/2"; - если заменить на var url=document.location.href;  не помогает

Comment: @SergSergN а document.location.href что выводит? Вы вывели эту ссылку в href? В href вы хотите выводить абсолютные или относительные ссылки?